# Extract URLs automatically by industry names

Tags: url, find

So I searched a lot about this, but all I found was how to extract titles from URLs.

What I want for example is, I have this name "AB Electronics Inc."
So when you type that in google the first thing that pops up is [www.abelectronicsinc.com/](http://www.abelectronicsinc.com/)

That's all I want, I want to know how to automate this, because I have like 1000 names, I dont want to type all these names one by one. I have a text file with all these names. Like:

```
ABIOMED, Inc.         
Accumold®         
Accuratus Lab Services        
Accutron Inc.         
Acme Monaco       
Acorn Product Development
```

And SO on.

So how do I find the url for those names directly is what I wish to know.

Thank you

Comment: You'll probably have to add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. Maybe include what programming languages you know. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No, I don't know any programming and this was urgent, I don't want to take a week of programming classes for this. I just needed some help. The only thing I tried was googling " how to extract urls by company or industry names".

Comment: Unfortunately you probably aren't going to find anyone who will do free work for you, you can always hire someone on freelancer.com.

Comment: Actually, I just tested. Acorn Product Development's website is www.acornpd.com, you could never write a program that could simply figure that out without it running hundreds of internet search queries. It certainly wouldn't be an easy application to build.

Comment: Okay, I figured this was something very rare, because even google couldn't give me any proper suggestions on this. I guess I'll have to hire somebody to build one for me then. Thank you for your time. Appreciate it.